# Notation in two-level regression model

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, references, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

In [this pdf](https://www.google.com.bd/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjQuYzmk5zHAhUOBI4KHWWxABo&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjoophox.net%2Fpublist%2Fmethodology05.pdf&ei=FFzHVdDfC46IuATl4oLQAQ&usg=AFQjCNEogRVqsG2rkPHhNjIQ3l8664jugw&bvm=bv.99804247,d.c2E), formula of two-level regression model is written as :

$$Y_{ij}=\beta_{0j}+\beta_{1j}X_{ij}+e_{ij}$$

and in the pdf $e_{ij}$ is referred as individual level **Residual** . But I am not understanding why it is residual instead of population **Error**,$\epsilon_{ij}$ ? If it can be written as

$$Y_{ij}=\beta_{0j}+\beta_{1j}X_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij}$$

, can  I also write the intraclass correlation (ICC) , $\rho$ as

$$\rho=\frac{\sigma^2_{U0}}{(\sigma^2_{U0}+\sigma^2_\epsilon)}$$

?

Comment: The two should be the same in terms of notations. $e_{ij}$ is also referred as "residual errors" in the pdf. Rigorously speaking, residuals are the realizations of errors, as elaborated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals).